# SQL default value error when uploading files using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, controller

i'm trying to upload multiple images using laravel and so far i've succeded, but the problem is that when i try to save text **AND** the files i get an error.
So far i've received so many errors that i can't remember all of then, but the latest is:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'title' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `posts` (`image`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (["italian.jpg"], 2019-05-23 18:48:22, 2019-05-23 18:48:22))

i've set the sql properly, and as i said, if i remove the image upload it works, and if i remove the text fields it also work, but **if i try both i doesnt**.
if i remember correctly when i remove the required fields it also works.

public function store(Request $request)
    {
              //dd($request);

```
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required|min:3|max:120',
        'text' => 'required',
        'image' => 'required',
        'image.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'
    ]);

    if($request->hasfile('image')){
        foreach($request->file('image') as $image)
        {
            $name=$image->getClientOriginalName();
            $image->move(public_path().'/images/', $name);  
            $data[] = $name;  
        }
    } else{
        redirect('/posts')->with('Error', 'no image');
    }

    $post->image=json_encode($data);

    $post = Post::create($validatedData);

    return redirect('/posts')->with('success', 'yay');

}
```

i also tried this, but it returns

> Creating default object from empty value

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
     $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required|min:3|max:120',
        'category' => 'required|min:3|max:120',
        'text' => 'required',
        'image' => 'required',
        'image.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);


    if($request->hasfile('image'))
     {

        foreach($request->file('image') as $image)
        {
            $name=$image->getClientOriginalName();
            $image->move(public_path().'/images/', $name);  
            $data[] = $name;  
        }
     }

     $post = new Post();
     $post->image=json_encode($data);


    $post->save();

    return back()->with('success', 'Yay');



}
```

Comment: Are there 2 `store` methods in your class??

Comment: make sure you've a `fillable title` property in your model

Comment: It looks like you are not passing value to the field title/text/category but those fields are required. Please make sure you have those fields in your view(blade) and have value.

Comment: sorry for the mess, i was in a hurry when i posted the question. There is one store method only, the last one is only something i tried and that also failed. Yes, the fields are all fillable and i am sending the values in the view. As i said, if i try **only** the text fields it works, and if i try **only** the images it also works. the problem is when i try both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured it out, hehe. just had to remove these lines:

`'image' => 'required',
 'image.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'`

Thanks anyways.